# Continue instead of 'or die' in Perl

Tags: loops, perl

I have a loop in my Perl script that prepares and executes a SQL statement, like this:

```
my $sql_1 = select * from TABLE; 
my $sth_1 = $database->prepare($sql_1) or die "Failed to prepare SQL"; 
$sth_1->execute() or die "Failed to execute SQL"; 
my $results = sth_1-> fetchall_arrayref({}); 

my params_ins; 
my params_del; 

foreach my $row($results) { 
  params_ins = $row->{params_ins} 
  params_del = $row->{params_del} 

  my $sql_2 = 
    begin transaction 
      exec delete_sp(params_ins) 
      exec insert_sp(params_del) 
    end transaction 

  my $sth_2 = $database->prepare($sql_2) or die "Failed to prepare SQL"; 
  $sth_2->execute(); 
}
```

As I understand, die will cause the execution of the code to stop. Would it be possible to continue to the next loop instead of stopping the whole execution of the script? For example, would it be possible to do something like:

```
  my $sth_2 = $database->prepare($sql_2) or continue; 
  $sth_2->execute();
```

Would 'or next' work?

Comment: You could wrap this in a `try{} catch{}` block using [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) and get the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent of C's `continue` is called `next` in Perl (and the equivalent of `break` in loops is `last`).

```
my $sth_2 = $database->prepare( $sql_2 )
   or do {
      warn( "Failed to prepare SQL: $DBI::errstr" );
      next;
   };
```

or

```
my $sth_2 = $database->prepare( $sql_2 );
if ( !$sth_2 ) {
   warn( "Failed to prepare SQL: $DBI::errstr" );
   next;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [next](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html) function.

Comment: You mean I can replace or die with or next?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `die` with `warn`. `die` outputs an error message and exits the script; `warn` outputs an error message and does not exit the script.

```
my $sth = $database->prepare($sql) or warn "Failed to prepare SQL";
$sth->execute() or warn "Failed to execute SQL";
```

Comment: That will kill the program if prepare fails (for calling `->execute` on an undefined value).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one additional solution here, you could use a try-catch block (called eval in perl).

```
eval {
  my $sth_2 = $database->prepare($sql_2) or die "Failed to prepare SQL $DBI::errstr"; 
  $sth_2->execute(); 
};
if($@) {
  warn "Error executing $sql2 => $@";
  next;
}
```

Comment: If this is the sort of thing you want to do, you can use DBI's `RaiseError` to die automatically.

Comment: There are 2 issues here. If you are editing an existing application, you cannot change the behavior by adding RaiseError in the connect-call. And raise-error won't allow you to clarify the message. In my experience, RaiseError is an option sometimes valuable for short skripts.